# How can I use update method for each record with condidation?

Tags: odoo

for example I want to update the price of products with a price of zero dollars to 100.

```
for price_list_items in (self.env['product.pricelist.item'].search_read([], [])):

    if price_list_items.price == 0:
        price_list_items.price = 100
```

But It's not working.

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'price'
```

How can I make such a update like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it this way :

```
list_of_pricelist = self.env['product.pricelist.item'].search([])

for pricelist in list_of_pricelist:
    if price_list_items.price == 0:
        price_list_items.price = 100
```

I think you better use search() in your case.

Difference between search() and search_read() :

https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/difference-between-search-and-search-read-in-odoo-8-83076
Search_read() returns a list of dict.

If you really want to do your code this way, i think you can do it like this, but it's not usual

```
for price_list_items in (self.env['product.pricelist.item'].search_read([], [])):

    if price_list_items[<list_index:int>]['field_name'] == 0:
        price_list_items[<list_index:int>].update({'field_name': value})
```

Answer (score 1):

The [search_read](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/odoo/models.py#L5031) function returns a list of dicts, `price_list_items` is a dict of one record field values

Setting the price using the following syntax is available for recordsets:

```
price_list_recod.price = 100
```

Instead of fetching and reading all records, you can simply search for price list items with a price equal to `0.0` using the `search` method (which will return a recordset) and then update the price for all of them with one assignment

***Example*:**

```
self.env['product.pricelist.item'].search([('price', '=', 0)]).price = 100
```